# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. On LocalHost

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".link").click(function(){
   var id = this.id;

   if(id == 'b1'){
      $( "#conteudo" ).load( "teste.html", function(){
      alert('Carregou de boa !');
   });
   }      
   });
</script>
```

All my pages are in localhost, I'm doing this just for study.
And this is the error that *Chrome* is giving me when I press the *B1* button:

**UPDATE** Full Error:

```
OPTIONS file:///E:/mypath/folder/page.html No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'   
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this locally, make sure you are visiting your page over `http` and not the `file` protocol.

Also, just to make sure you're going to same origin, you can add `//` to the link like so:

```
$( "#conteudo" ).load( "//teste.html", function(){
```

You can pick up a local virtual machine webserver ([Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) here: http://virtualboxes.org/images/

Comment: Now I'm getting only 1 error, this one:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://teste.html/. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. *

Comment: Indeed, you're not going to be able to do XMLHttpRequest over file:/// protocol

Comment: So, I can not use it on localhost ?! D:

Comment: You can use it on localhost, but only if you go to it over http://, not file:///.  You'll need to have a local webserver running, or a virtualmachine with a webserver built in, in order to run it. I suggested a virtual machine, because you can get one pre-configured. Otherwise you'll have to configure your local one.

Comment: I don't know what OS you are running, otherwise I would suggest a set up guide.

Comment: You were right ! I turned Xaamp online, and it worked D:

Could you give me some explaination exatcly why it only gets http:// ?

Comment: It's because file protocol is an entirely different protocol than Http. Your browser is able to interpret the markup from the `file` protocol, but it's not truly http, which `XMLHttpRequest` must use (it's in the name ;)). As well, same origin policy sees the different protocols as different origins and therefore can't do anything with an `XMLHttpRequest` that's requested by a page on the `file:///` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome only does `XMLHttpRequest`s over http(s). Use `http://localhost` instead of `file://localhost`

Comment: Really man? It's a really big path D:

I'll do this for as a job later, how may I do that when I update this to the server?

Like: 

public_html/ajax/page.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed run SimpleHTTPServer with:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If you do this in the same dir where your web files are located you will have a webserver running in a very easy way

Comment: I don't think I have it'-'

Comment: if you use windows you could install cygwin, gitbash or something similar.